# mobx - Leading decorators must be attached to a class declaration

Tags: reactjs, electron, mobx

I want to use the MobX decorators, but when I try to run my code, I get the following error message:

```
Leading decorators must be attached to a class declaration
```

My application is storing data in Datastores from nedb and I want to observe them with mobx.

So for example, if I have the following code:

```
import { observable } from 'mobx';
import Datastore from 'nedb';

@observable projectsDb = new Datastore({
    filename: __dirname + './projects.json',
    autoload: true,
    timestampData: true,
});

export default projectsDb;
```

When I start my Electron App I use the following command:

```
"browserify -t [ babelify --presets [ react es2015 stage-1] --plugins [transform-decorators-legacy] ] app/app.jsx -o app/js/app.js && stylus app/css/styles.styl -o app/css/styles.css && electron app/main.js",
```

Also all devDepenendencies and Dependencies are added to my package.json.

Is there any error in my "start"-command or any misunderstanding in the concept of observable here?

Comment: I think the `observable` decorator can be used only on a class property. Try making `projectsDb` a class property and see if it changes anything. Also, I would try to wrap `projectsDb` inside an object and see if it changes anything (not sure if it is a proper solution, it's just to see if it works).

Comment: @DorWeid Thank you for your suggestion. I wrapped my projectsDb in a class and used the 'observable' decorator, without an error. Now I hope I can get my app logic to work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Decorators (in general) can not be applied to variables, only to classes and properties. However, `observable` can also be invoked as funcion (so without the `@`), and then you can objects into it as well.

P.S. note that MobX does modify the internals of external libraries, so passing your entire database class to `observable` will not magically make your whole database lib reactive, it will just create an [observable reference](https://mobxjs.github.io/mobx/refguide/boxed.html) to the database

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So if I got you right to make these datastores reactive, I have to wrap the datastores in a class, and declare variables which contain the values of those datastores. Then declare a function in this new class which is modifying the Database and then refreshing the variables ? Could this work ?

Comment: Yep that should be a fine start. As soon as your data is stored in observables you can start working for it. To sync to the Database on updates and such you can use reaction / autoruns. And for the other way around the database probably has a subscription mechanism? Or just sync on initial reads

Comment: I am using nedb as my local database. It sadly has no subscription method, as far as I know. I think I will go on with sync on the initial variables. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 5):

you can remove semicolon after decorator :

turn this :

```
@inject(CssAnimator);
```

to this:

```
@inject(CssAnimator)
```